# implemeting java application update with AppLoader.java

Tags: java, auto-update

I hava a java swing application and would like to use auto update using AppLoader.java class that i found online at

[**https://reportmill.wordpress.com/2014/12/04/automatically-update-your-javapackager-applications/
**](https://reportmill.wordpress.com/2014/12/04/automatically-update-your-javapackager-applications/)

has anybody had any experience with this class. i can not seem to implement this class with my application and am getting errors:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\home\Documents\NetBeansProjects\test_update\build\classes (Access is denied)

and

java.lang.RuntimeException: Main Jar not found!

Comment: Add the source code please

Answer (score 0):

yep, the code seems not working. I did some modification for the code to make it work. please do as follows:

1. download the file through http://reportmill.com/snap1/SnapCode1.jar.pack.gz
2. copy this file to C:\Users\home\Documents\NetBeansProjects\test_update\build\classes
3. copy and paste the code below and give it a run

   import java.io.*;
   import java.lang.reflect.Method;
   import java.net.*;
   import java.text.*;
   import java.util.jar.*;
   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.util.zip .GZIPInputStream;

   ```
   /**
    * This app
    */

   public class AppLoader {

   // Constants
   static final String AppDirName = "SnapCode";
   static final String JarName = "SnapCode1.jar";
   static final String JarURL = "http://reportmill.com/snap1/SnapCode1.jar.pack.gz";
   static final String MainClass = "snap.app.App";

   /**
    * Main method - reinvokes main1() on Swing thread in exception handler.
    */
   public static void main(final String args[]) {
       // Invoke real main with exception handler
       try {
           main1(args);
       } catch (Throwable e) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   /**
    * Main method: - Gets main Jar file from default, if missing - Updates main
    * Jar file from local update file, if previously loaded - Load main Jar
    * into URLClassLoader, load main class and invoke main method - Check for
    * update from remove site in background
    */
   public static void main1(final String args[]) throws Exception {
       // Make sure default jar is in place
       try {
           copyDefaultMainJar();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       // If Update Jar exists, copy it into place
       File jar = getAppFile(JarName);
       File updateJar = getAppFile(JarName + ".update");
       if (updateJar.exists()) {
           copyFile(updateJar, jar);
           jar.setLastModified(updateJar.lastModified());
           updateJar.delete();
       }

       // If jar doesn't exist complain bitterly
       if (!jar.exists() || !jar.canRead())
           throw new RuntimeException("Main Jar not found!");

       // Check for updates in background thread
       if (args.length == 0 || !args[0].equals("-snap"))
           new Thread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   checkForUpdatesSilent();
               }
           }).start();

       // Create URLClassLoader for main jar file, get App class and invoke
       // main
   //      URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(
   //              new URL[] { jar.toURI().toURL() });
   //      Class cls = ucl.loadClass(MainClass); // ucl.close();
   //      Method meth = cls.getMethod("main", new Class[] { String[].class });
   //      meth.invoke(null, new Object[] { args });
   //      if (cls == Object.class)
   //          ((Closeable) ucl).close(); // Getting rid of warning message for ucl
   }

   /**
    * Copies the default main jar into place for initial run.
    */
   private static void copyDefaultMainJar() throws IOException, ParseException {
       // Get main jar from app package and get location of working jar file
       URL url = AppLoader.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
               .getLocation();
       String path0 = url.getPath();
       path0 = URLDecoder.decode(path0, "UTF-8");

       path0 = path0 + "SnapCode1.jar.pack.gz" ;
       File jar0 = getAppFile(JarName);
       File jar1 = new File(path0);

       // If app package main jar is newer, copy it into place and set time
       if (jar0.exists() && jar0.lastModified() >= jar1.lastModified())
           return;
       copyFile(jar1, jar0);
   }

   /**
    * Check for updates.
    */
   private static void checkForUpdatesSilent() {
       try {
           checkForUpdates();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   /**
    * Check for updates.
    */
   private static void checkForUpdates() throws IOException,
           MalformedURLException {
       // Get URL connection and lastModified time
       File jarFile = getAppFile(JarName);
       URL url = new URL(JarURL);
       URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
       long mod0 = jarFile.lastModified(), mod1 = connection.getLastModified();
       if (mod0 >= mod1) {
           System.out.println("No update available at " + JarURL + '(' + mod0
                   + '>' + mod1 + ')');
           return;
       }

       // Get update file and write to JarName.update
       System.out.println("Loading update from " + JarURL);
       byte bytes[] = getBytes(connection);
       System.out.println("Update loaded");
       File updatePacked = getAppFile(JarName + ".pack.gz"), updateFile = getAppFile(JarName
               + ".update");
       writeBytes(updatePacked, bytes);
       System.out.println("Update saved: " + updatePacked);
       unpack(updatePacked, updateFile);
       System.out.println("Update unpacked: " + updateFile);
       updateFile.setLastModified(mod1);
       updatePacked.delete();

       // Let the user know
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               JOptionPane
                       .showMessageDialog(null,
                               "A new update is available. Restart application to apply");
           }
       });
   }

   /**
    * Returns the Main jar file.
    */
   private static File getAppFile(String aName) {
       return new File(getAppDir(), aName);
   }

   /**
    * Returns the Main jar file.
    */
   private static File getAppDir() {
       return getAppDataDir(AppDirName, true);
   }

   /**
    * 
    * Utility Methods for AppLoader.
    * 
    */

   /**
    * Copies a file from one location to another.
    */
   public static File copyFile(File aSource, File aDest) throws IOException {
       // Get input stream, output file and output stream
       FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(aSource);
       File out = aDest.isDirectory() ? new File(aDest, aSource.getName())
               : aDest;
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(out);

       // Iterate over read/write until all bytes written
       byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
       for (int i = fis.read(buf); i != -1; i = fis.read(buf))
           fos.write(buf, 0, i);

       // Close in/out streams and return out file
       fis.close();
       fos.close();
       return out;
   }

   /**
    * Writes the given bytes (within the specified range) to the given file.
    */
   public static void writeBytes(File aFile, byte theBytes[])
           throws IOException {
       if (theBytes == null) {
           aFile.delete();
           return;
       }
       FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(aFile);
       fileStream.write(theBytes);
       fileStream.close();
   }

   /**
    * Unpacks the given file into the destination file.
    */
   public static File unpack(File aFile, File aDestFile) throws IOException {
       // Get dest file - if already unpacked, return
       File destFile = getUnpackDestination(aFile, aDestFile);
       if (destFile.exists() && destFile.lastModified() > aFile.lastModified())
           return destFile;

       // Create streams: FileInputStream -> GZIPInputStream -> JarOutputStream
       // -> FileOutputStream
       FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(aFile);
       GZIPInputStream gzipInput = new GZIPInputStream(fileInput);
       FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
       JarOutputStream jarOut = new JarOutputStream(fileOut);

       // Unpack file
       Pack200.newUnpacker().unpack(gzipInput, jarOut);

       // Close streams
       fileInput.close();
       gzipInput.close();
       jarOut.close();
       fileOut.close();

       // Return destination file
       return destFile;
   }

   /**
    * Returns the file that given packed file would be saved to using the
    * unpack method.
    */
   public static File getUnpackDestination(File aFile, File aDestFile) {
       // Get dest file - if null, create from packed file minus .pack.gz
       File destFile = aDestFile;
       if (destFile == null)
           destFile = new File(aFile.getPath().replace(".pack.gz", ""));

       // If dest file is directory, change to file inside with packed file
       // minus .pack.gz
       else if (destFile.isDirectory())
           destFile = new File(destFile, aFile.getName().replace(".pack.gz",
                   ""));

       // Return destination file
       return destFile;
   }

   /**
    * Returns the AppData or Application Support directory file.
    */
   public static File getAppDataDir(String aName, boolean doCreate) {
       // Get user home + AppDataDir (platform specific) + name (if provided)
       String dir = System.getProperty("user.home");
       if (isWindows)
           dir += File.separator + "AppData" + File.separator + "Local";
       else if (isMac)
           dir += File.separator + "Library" + File.separator
                   + "Application Support";
       if (aName != null)
           dir += File.separator + aName;

       // Create file, actual directory (if requested) and return
       File dfile = new File(dir);
       if (doCreate && aName != null)
           dfile.mkdirs();
       return dfile;
   }

   /**
    * Returns bytes for connection.
    */
   public static byte[] getBytes(URLConnection aConnection) throws IOException {
       InputStream stream = aConnection.getInputStream(); // Get stream for
                                                           // connection
       byte bytes[] = getBytes(stream); // Get bytes for stream
       stream.close(); // Close stream
       return bytes; // Return bytes
   }

   /**
    * Returns bytes for an input stream.
    */
   public static byte[] getBytes(InputStream aStream) throws IOException {
       ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       byte chunk[] = new byte[8192];
       for (int len = aStream.read(chunk, 0, 8192); len > 0; len = aStream
               .read(chunk, 0, 8192))
           bs.write(chunk, 0, len);
       return bs.toByteArray();
   }

   // Whether Windows/Mac
   static boolean isWindows = (System.getProperty("os.name")
           .indexOf("Windows") >= 0);
   static boolean isMac = (System.getProperty("os.name").indexOf("Mac OS X") >= 0);
   ```

   }

Your problem is that in your copyFile method FileInputStream takes a wrong File object

Comment: i am able to access the jar file online but it doesn't update the application.

Comment: Same problem here. The code downloads the last version from the website, it is unpacked and rename "JarName.update" in the "AppDirName" folder and the application correctly notifies the user to restart. When I run again my application the "JarName.update" replaces the old "JarName" as I expect. I think the problem is that URLClassLoader is not running "JarName" just updated, but it looks like it runs the main class in my package folder.